# AWS laravel forbidden

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to install Laravel in an AWS/EC2 instance.  I first tried to install in my home directory.  The laravel new command worked well, and installs the subdirectory.  I changed /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf in the document root and directory sections (see below) to reflect the path to the public subdirectory of the laravel installation.  I restarted the apache server.  I changed the permissions (recursively) on the storage subdirectory of the Laravel installation to 777.  I realize the eventually this change to 777 needs to change to 775 with a chown to the web user, but I would like to get this to work first.

This configuration produces a "forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server." response.

I tried to install laravel in /var/www .  I renamed the "html" directory.  The "laravel new html" command produces the error

PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/laravel_42427584d5fd657ed6d5af1886e70011.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/ec2-user/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 114

This appears to be a permissions issue, so I tried sudo laravel new html.  This produces "sudo: laravel command not found".  I added ~/.composer/vendor/bin to my path.

My preference would be to install Laravel in my home directory, but installation anywhere that works would be fine.

Searches in stackoverflow (and the general web) produced solutions suggesting changing the ownership of the laravel installation directory apache:apache (produced the same forbiden error) and reviewing the apache error log (permission denied to enter /var/log/httpd even with sudo, chmod for this directory did not change result).

I have included the httpd.conf file.  Thank you in advance for your help.

httpd.conf file (relevant parts)

```
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user/laravel_dir/public"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
#<Directory "/var/www/html">
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/laravel_dir/public">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
```

ExecCGI       MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
     ...
        #AllowOverride None
        AllowOverride All
    ...
        Require all granted

Comment: /usr/sbin/httpd -t command reports that syntax is OK

Comment: any logs from httpd?

Comment: You must stop thinking that it works like a VPS.